# Off-the-shelf UI for managing AWS Cognito user-profiles?

Tags: amazon-cognito

Much like AWS provides hosted UI for sign-up/in for Cognito, does there exist an app to modify user-profiles stored in Cognito?

I am looking for either hosted service or a GitHub project I can host myself.

The closest I found so far is https://github.com/MetaMetricsInc/django-warrant. It allows to get Django-app up and running, which uses Cognito as auth back-end and has profile-views. But it's not designed to be integrated into other apps (no AWS UI's like redirect-destination).